# How do I start breaking down a project?

Tags: web, project

I want to start a project for myself, and build a portfolio website from start to end.
How do I do this?
What steps should I be taking?

some things that I think I should do are these, but I don't know how and when I should do these:

- creating wireframes
- creating UML for classes
- preparing user stories
- Analyzing and designing the system architecture
- choosing the right tools

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, prepare your content, you can also research and gather inspiration from other people's portfolios.

Then prepare some user stories to try to cover edge cases too and create wireframes/designs for each story. While designing systems it's a good idea to identify your design token such as typography, colors, etc.

You can also create a UML diagram to help visualize the system, which can be optional for a simple portfolio.

Now just select the right tools and technology for your project. For a simple portfolio HTML, CSS, and javascript are sufficient but for a complicated application such as eCommerce, it would be better to give a try to some frameworks (Angular/React/Next), databases (SQL/NoSql), and cloud technology(Azure/AWS).

Finally, look for a hosting and domain, it depends on your budget. At the development/testing stage, you can select any free hosting (Netlify/Firebase/Github pages).

Don't expect perfection in one go, learn and improvise the project. More importantly, enjoy the process and make it efficient.